# sp_blitz Monitoring and Alerts

Tags: sql-server, alert

I'd like to use sp_blitz for Monitoring.  I have Alerts 16 - 25 configured, as well as 823, 824, 825.

These are the names:

```
Fatal Error Database  Integrity Suspect Severity 023
Fatal Error in Current Process Severity 020
Fatal Error in Database Process Severity 021
Fatal Error in Resource Severity 019
Fatal Error Severity 025
Fatal Error Table Integrity Suspect Severity 022
Hardware Error Severity 024
Insufficient Resources Severity 017
IO Error Corruption Error Number 824
Memory Error Error Number 823
Misc User Error Severity 016
Nonfatal Internal Error Severity 018
Possible IO Error Corruption Error Number 825
```

I have the alerts configured, an operator, and the notification sent to email for that operator.  I have all of the alerts configured, but sp_blitz is not finding

Since I'm new at sp_blitz, and MS SQL, I'm searching to see if I've done something not right, or at least not right for sp_blitz which is such a great tool.  I named the alerts to be more informational, could that be an issue?

Executing sp_blitz shows errors in the FindingsGroup 'Monitoring' for (1) alerts not configured with a followup, No alerts for corruption, no alerts for sev 19-25, no operators configured, No operators enabled, not all alerts are configured.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible that you've found a bug. (I know, right? Impossible!)

The nice thing about open source is that you can just edit it. Look at the script, and do a control-F to find the section of the script that matches up with the alerts you're getting. I promise, it's super-simple to read.

Then, copy out that query, and try to run it. Look at which DMVs appear to be giving false results. Maybe an alert is disabled, for example.

Then, if you think you've found a bug, file a bug report over in the [Github repo for the First Responder Kit.](http://firstresponderkit.org) Read down that page - there's plenty of info there on how to contribute, file issues, and get help.